# SQLite as project file to use in WPF app

Tags: c#, wpf, database, sqlite, file

What is the best practice when using SQLite as file in wpf app.
I have a database driven app and I want to use SQLite as a file per project. But I'm very green in programming.

Is it correct that each time the user makes a new project the app makes a new database file, holding a fixed table structure that can be used in the app?

This means that each sqlite database file has a unique name and all the dbconnections that are made in the app should correspond to read and write to that file.

Now my read and write dbmethods are spread out over a few viewmodels and how do I dynamically change

```
String dbConnectionString = @"Data Source =projectA.sqlite";
```

to

```
String dbConnectionString = @"Data Source =projectB.sqlite";
String dbConnectionString = @"Data Source =projectC.sqlite";
```

each one corresponding to the project they want to load and work on in the app.
I don't find much info about this matter on the web.

Maybe someone can explain me what the best practice is or how sqlite dB are used as files for a wpf app.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it correct that each time the user makes a new project the app makes a new database file,

No. This is only the case if you program your app in such a way that it picks a new filename for the database file every time.

> holding a fixed table structure that can be used in the app?

Not necessarily. You can change a table structure to some extent while your app is running, and this can also depend on user input.

> This means that each sqlite database file has a unique name

Only if you actively make sure it is unique.

> and all the dbconnections that are made in the app should correspond to read and write to that file.

Only if you specify exactly the aforementioned unique filename for the connection. You can also open connections to any other more permanent/non-unique SQLite file from your app (and even to several at a time).

> Now my read and write dbmethods are spread out over a few viewmodels and how do I dynamically change (...)

Provide a place that is somewhat global in your app (either a static class, or a central configuration class an instance of which is passed around to each of your modules) that returns the filename from a read-only property. In all of your DB-related methods, use the information from that property rather than a hard-coded string.